# Error: Plugin 0 specified in "base" provided an invalid property of "Instrumenter"

Tags: webpack, karma-runner, babeljs

I'm trying to configure Karma to run react/redux tests written in mocha and chai, but am encountering the following error:

```
WARNING in ./src/Actions/menu-actions.test.js
  Module build failed: Error: Plugin 0 specified in "base" provided an invalid property of "Instrumenter"
  at Plugin.init (/Users/adc/project/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/plugin.js:131:13)
at Function.normalisePlugin (/Users/adc/project/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:152:12)
  at /Users/adc/project/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:184:30
  at Array.map (native)
  at Function.normalisePlugins (/Users/adc/project/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:158:20)
  at OptionManager.mergeOptions (/Users/adc/project/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:234:36)
  at OptionManager.init (/Users/adc/project/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:368:12)
  at File.initOptions (/Users/adc/project/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:212:65)
  at new File (/Users/adc/project/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:135:24)
  at Pipeline.transform (/Users/adc/project/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/pipeline.js:46:16)
  at transpile (/Users/adc/project/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:46:20)
at Object.module.exports (/Users/adc/project/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:163:20)
  @ ./src \.test.jsx?$
  @ ./testing/test-bundler.specs.js
```

This looks like it has something to do with the webpack testing config I'm using:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json-loader' },
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'null-loader' },

      { test: /\.jsx?$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: [/node_modules/] },
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: [/node_modules/, /specs/],
        query: { plugins: ['istanbul'] },
      },
      { test: /\.jpe?g$|\.gif$|\.png$|\.svg$/i, loader: 'null-loader' },
    ],
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV),
      },
    }),
  ],

  resolve: {
    modules: [
      path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
      'src',
      'node_modules',
    ],
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
  },

  externals: {
    jsdom: 'window',
    'react/addons': true,
    'react/lib/ExecutionEnvironment': true,
    'react/lib/ReactContext': 'window',
  },
};
```

I have already been through the config and made some adjustments to migrate it to the latest version of webpack, but I can't see any further areas of incompatibility.

For completion, here is my full karma config, and the file that is throwing the error:

```
// testing/karma.conf.js

const webpackConfig = require('./webpack.test.config');

module.exports = (config) => {
  config.set({
    frameworks: ['mocha', 'chai'],
    browsers: ['Chrome'],

    files: [
      {
        pattern: './test-bundler.specs.js',
        watched: false,
        served: true,
        included: true,
      },
    ],

    preprocessors: {
      './test-bundler.specs.js': ['webpack', 'sourcemap'],
    },

    webpack: webpackConfig,

    webpackMiddleware: {
      noInfo: true,
      stats: 'errors-only',
    },

    reporters: ['mocha', 'coverage'],

    mochaReporter: {
      output: 'autowatch',
    },

    coverageReporter: {
      reporters: [
        {
          type: 'lcov',
          dir: 'coverage',
        },
        { type: 'text-summary' },
      ],
    },

    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_ERROR,
  });
};

// testing/test-bundler.specs.js
import 'babel-polyfill';

const context = require.context('../src', true, /\.test.jsx?$/);
context.keys().forEach(context);

// src/Actions/menu-actions.test.js

import * as menuActions from './menu-actions';

describe('menuActions', () => {
  describe('updateVisibleMenuItems', () => {
    it('updateVisibleMenuItems returns action type and onboarding code',
      () => {
        const result = menuActions.updateVisibleMenuItems(4);

        expect(result).to.deep.equal({
          type: 'UPDATE_VISIBLE_MENU_ITEMS',
          onboardingStage: 4,
        });
      });


    it('updateVisibleMenuItems handles different onboarding codes',
      () => {
        const result = menuActions.updateVisibleMenuItems(5);

        expect(result).to.deep.equal({
          type: 'UPDATE_VISIBLE_MENU_ITEMS',
          onboardingStage: 5,
        });
      });
  });
});
```

Comment: Did you find a fix for that, if so, please add here. I am facing same issue in my production deployment, but not in qa environments or localhost.

Comment: @xploreraj, sorry no, this remains unresolved. I just switched to jasmine.

Comment: It got resolved by removing `"plugins": ["istanbul"]` from `.babelrc`. Here is my issue completely, little different than yours. https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/8173